# Count by range only returns one row

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying get an output to use on a different CALL.
output i want is

```
Row   |   Col   |  Data  |  Seq

<70%  | Voters  |  5519  |  8
<80%  | Voters  |  4352  |  8
<90%  | Voters  |  3251  |  8
100%  | Voters  |  2511  |  8
```

the code i have is

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN (poll_propensity >= 0.70 AND perm_absentee = 'N' AND mail_propensity = 0)  THEN '< 70%' 
        WHEN (poll_propensity >= 0.80 AND perm_absentee = 'N' AND mail_propensity = 0)  THEN '< 80%' 
        WHEN (poll_propensity >= 0.90 AND perm_absentee = 'N' AND mail_propensity = 0)  THEN '< 90%'
        WHEN (poll_propensity >= 1 AND perm_absentee = 'N' AND mail_propensity = 0)     THEN '100%' 
       END AS Row,            

'Voters' AS Col,
COUNT(voter_id) AS Data,
8 AS Seq

FROM (  SELECT p.voter_id, p.perm_absentee, vp.poll_propensity, vp.mail_propensity 
        FROM VoterProfile p
             INNER JOIN DistrictPrecinct d ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code 
             INNER JOIN VoterPropensity vp ON p.voter_id=vp.voter_id        
        WHERE d.district_id= 3 AND vp.election_type= 'T' ) as derived 
GROUP BY Row
```

but all im getting output is like

```
Row   |   Col   |  Data  |  Seq

<70%  | Voters  |  5519  |  8
```

only one comes through if anyone can help that would be great

Comment: You need to simply change the orders of the whens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the orders of the WHEN statements  since 1 > .7 the 1's are being lumped in with the .7 you need to start with .1 and then go down to the .7.

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN (poll_propensity >= 1 AND perm_absentee = 'N' AND mail_propensity = 0)     THEN '100%' 
        WHEN (poll_propensity >= 0.90 AND perm_absentee = 'N' AND mail_propensity = 0)  THEN '< 90%'
        WHEN (poll_propensity >= 0.80 AND perm_absentee = 'N' AND mail_propensity = 0)  THEN '< 80%' 
        WHEN (poll_propensity >= 0.70 AND perm_absentee = 'N' AND mail_propensity = 0)  THEN '< 70%' 
       END AS Row,            

'Voters' AS Col,
COUNT(voter_id) AS Data,
8 AS Seq

FROM (  SELECT p.voter_id, p.perm_absentee, vp.poll_propensity, vp.mail_propensity 
        FROM VoterProfile p
             INNER JOIN DistrictPrecinct d ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code 
             INNER JOIN VoterPropensity vp ON p.voter_id=vp.voter_id        
        WHERE d.district_id= 3 AND vp.election_type= 'T' ) as derived 
GROUP BY Row
```

Alternatively, you could change the operation from >= to < and leave the order the same; but I'm not sure that's going to give you the same subset your looking for.

Comment: This works but it subtracts from the main count. for example it says 100% is 4600 and 90% is 256 but 90% should be 4856 (addition of both)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the resultset returned from a statement like this:

```
SELECT r.Row
     , 'Voters' AS Col
     , CASE r.Row
         WHEN '< 70%' THEN IFNULL(d.c70,0)
         WHEN '< 80%' THEN IFNULL(d.c80,0)
         WHEN '< 90%' THEN IFNULL(d.c90,0)
         WHEN '100%' THEN IFNULL(d.c100,0)
       END AS Data
     , 8 AS Seq
  FROM ( SELECT '< 70%' AS Row
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 80%' 
         UNION ALL SELECT '< 90%'
         UNION ALL SELECT '100%' 
       ) r
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 0.70 AND vp.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c70
              , SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 0.80 AND vp.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c80
              , SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 0.90 AND vp.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c90
              , SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 1    AND vp.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c100
              , COUNT(p.voter_id) AS count_voter_id
           FROM VoterProfile p
           JOIN DistrictPrecinct d ON d.precinct_id=p.precinct_code
           JOIN VoterPropensity vp ON p.voter_id=vp.voter_id
          WHERE d.district_id = 3
            AND vp.election_type = 'T'
       ) d
 ORDER BY r.Row
```

(It's a bit odd that you are using a comparison `>= 0.70` and then using a label of `'< 70%'` label. It looks like you might want a `<= 0.70` comparison instead.

From your data, it looks like you want the counts to be aggregated. A voter with a poll_propensity of .85 should be included in multiple counts. (You don't specifically state that, but that's what your expected output suggests to me.)

If that's not the case, if you want a voter count of just voters between the given percentages, I would just adjust the conditional tests to check the specific range, e.g.:

```
SUM(vp.poll_propensity >= 0.80 AND vp.poll_propensity < 0.90 
     AND vp.perm_absentee = 'N' AND vp.mail_propensity = 0) AS c80
```

Comment: this gives the output as i wanted i will plug in into my routine and see how it works out. Thanks for your work

Comment: OK I used this code in my code and works awesomely for Voters, but now I want to union this with the same thing but i want it to calculate households. So I changed the count to COUNT(HHKey) which is a household key for a household. but when i change it like that and at the bottom i say GROUP BY p.HHKey after AND vp.election_type = 'T' and it returns 30000 rows instead of 5... any help would greatly appreciated